# How to get vector magnitude using MathNET.Numerics?

Tags: c#, vector, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to get the magnitude of a vector and I tried using the `L2Norm()` method but there was a red line under it stating that `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Vector` does not contain a definition for `L2Norm` and no extension method `L2Norm` accepting a first argument of type `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Vector` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

I put,

```
using MathNet.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
```

At the top so I'm not sure why it's still showing an error. Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L2Norm` is only available in v3:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
Vector<double>.Build.Random(10).L2Norm();
```

In v2 you can use the `Norm` function (which is available in v3 as well) with p=2 as argument:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;
DenseVector.CreateRandom(10, new Normal()).Norm(2);
```